# Enable save button when value of text columns of data grid changes

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have data grid with some text columns and default value of all text column is 1. Also, i am using a button named 'save' which saves the values of text columns of data grid. 
My requirement is 'Save' button should only be enabled when value of text columns of data grid changes.Please help me.

Below is my code:-

```
    View:-
x:Name="datagrid_range_targets" local:SetMinWidthToAutoAttachedBehaviour.SetMinWidthToAuto="true"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding RangeData, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                  Margin="0,5,5,0"  Loaded="OnUserControlLoaded" Unloaded="OnUserControlUnloaded" Style="{StaticResource style_data_grid}">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style x:Key="errorStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="-2"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                            <Setter Property="ToolTip" 
                             Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                             Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>

            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="col_range_targets_range"
                                    Width="Auto"
                                    Binding="{Binding Name}"
                                    Header="Range" IsReadOnly="True" />

                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="col_budget_report_year1"
                                    Width="Auto" 
                                    Header="Year 01" EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource errorStyle}">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                        <Binding Path="budgetReportYear1" Mode="TwoWay"
                                >
                            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                <local:GreaterThanOrEqualLessThanOrEqual Max="99"
                                                                        Min=".0000001" />
                            </Binding.ValidationRules>
                        </Binding>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="col_budget_report_year2"
                                    Width="Auto" 
                                    Header="Year 02" EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource errorStyle}">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                        <Binding Path="budgetReportYear2" Mode="TwoWay"
                                 UpdateSourceTrigger="Default">
                            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                <local:GreaterThanOrEqualLessThanOrEqual Max="99"
                                                                         Min="0.0000001" />
                            </Binding.ValidationRules>
                        </Binding>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                </DataGridTextColumn>

 <Button x:Name="Save"  Click="btn_Set_mulutiplier_Click" Content="Set multiplier" 
                                               Style="{StaticResource button_SetMultiplier}"  />




               View Model-
                    private double _budgetReportYear1 = 1;
    private double _budgetReportYear2 = 1; public double budgetReportYear1
    {
        get { return _budgetReportYear1; }
        set
        {
            _budgetReportYear1 = value;
            Onchanged("budgetReportYear1");
        }
    }


    public double budgetReportYear2
    {
        get { return _budgetReportYear2; }
        set
        {
            _budgetReportYear2 = value;
            Onchanged("budgetReportYear2");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a property to your ViewModel:

```
private bool _columnModified = false;
public bool columnModified{
    get { return _columnModified; }
    set
    {
        _columnModified = value;
    }
}
```

Add this to your budgetReports setters:

```
columnModified = true;
```

And in your View set the button IsEnabled property binding to columnModified:

```
<Button Content="Save" IsEnabled="{Binding columnModified}"/>
```

You will also will have to turn your columnModified to false when the save is done.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have used the same approach but save button is still coming in enabled state. in my case ,as i mentioned above, i have used and set default value of datagridtext column as 1 in private property. i think that is the reason it is not working.

Comment: This solution is not working for my scenario. By default , Save button is enabled even after using IsEnabled="{Binding columnModified}".

Answer (score 0):

Change binding to

```
<Binding Path="budgetReportYear1" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
```

Now when each time user types in textbox the property changes. Inside setter, enable the button to true ie

Bind `IsEnabled` of save button to a bool property and set it to true.
On save button click, set the property to false as well to reset the button state.

Comment: This solution is not working . Save button is still displayed as enabled.

Comment: @Ram : It's just an idea on how to make it work. Just put break point and check while editing the text column, if the property setter is reached or if something is blocking. If you want, you can share the entire code needed to test it and I shall debug and help you out with a complete solution.

Comment: Hi, Thank you it is working fine now. In the same code for datagrid, i want undo and redo functionality . I mean if user doesnt click on save button and press close button ,all inserted value should  not be saved in data grid.